# Wifi strength in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c++

Does anyone have some code I can use in an iPhone app that will let me see strength of wifi? I have a connection intensive operation and prefer they aren't in a spotty zone

Comment: Apple has stated clearly in their documentation that they wouldn't accept any application with intensive networking requirements. You're taking a very risky decision.

Comment: I would like to see a solution to this as it would be quite useful when building Apps outside of the walled garden.

Answer (score 2):

This may help get you going on the right track .....

http://blog.vladalexa.com/2010/07/07/iphone-signal-testing-with-code/

Comment: While this app may help the OP get some information about the strength of the current cellular network, all the code it uses to do that are private and would get the app rejected immediately.

Comment: If what Jason said about the private API things were true, developers should never use such 3-party resources.

Comment: UNLESS you aren't developing for the app store.  Not every app is for the consumer...

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this is possible.

iOS and its SDK isolate applications from doing (and querying) most system-level things. What you could do is to use `[NSData dataWithContentsFromURL:...]` to do one or two HTTP requests to ensure that the connection is stable and then do the main data transfers.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to point those of you who land here to a great reference on this question.

Getting the wifi signal for your use on an iOS device:

[Accessing & Using the MobileWiFi.framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018110/accessing-using-the-mobilewifi-framework)