# Detecting Wi-Fi signal strength on iPhone

Tags: iphone, wifi

I have seen this post which referes to private APIs to achieve what am after

[Wifi strength in iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484500/wifi-strength-in-iphone-app)

but wanted to know if there is a legal way to do this. Looked around but could not find anything yet. I hope some one can give a hint

Cheers
AF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use another way instead.
For example you can post a request. Calculate the time when you get the respond.

Maybe you post a request to http://stackoverflow.com
And you get the respond in 1.0s, assign the wifi is very strong.
In 5.0s,assign the wifi is weak.

Maybe the way is not exact but is useful.
sorry for my poor English :)

Comment: thanks for that. i came across this suggestion but thought i should just check if there is another resort :) thanks any ways

Comment: That won't tell you the signal strength of a wifi connection. It is entirely feasible that you can have a fast ping on a bad connection and a slow ping on a good connection.

Answer (score 0):

I've searched through all the relevant bits of the SDK and there is nothing.
And as you know, if it's not in the SDK and you use it your app will not get approved.

Comment: i downloaded Viber, for free calls over wifi,  and found that they give indication of the quality of the call when the call is on going. I believe they are giving this indication based on the wifi signal strength. Maybe they have another thing sunning in the background which decides this not sure.

Comment: It is most probably judging the quality on the number of dropped packets. Again, not really an indication of the strength of the wifi connection - VOIP quality != wifi strength.